# How to show the daily tasks in day's agenda but not in week's agenda?

Tags: org-mode

I have a few tasks in my agenda that I'd like to complete every day, e.g. `SCHEDULED: <2016-04-04 Mon 16:30 +1d>`.

Obviously I like to see them in the daily agenda, and that works fine. Here's what I'm using:

```cl
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      `(
        ;; ...
        ("d" "Daily Action List"
             ((agenda ""
                      ((org-agenda-ndays 1)
                       (org-agenda-sorting-strategy
                        (quote ((agenda time-up priority-down tag-up))))
                       (org-deadline-warning-days 0)))))))

(defun orfu-agenda-day ()
  (interactive)
  (org-agenda nil "d"))
```

However, when I switch to the weekly view (with <kbd>w</kbd>), the daily tasks obscure the whole thing, since each of them is now repeated 7 times.

How could I hide all tasks that have `+1d` in them from the weekly view? If it helps, I could tag the headings they are in with e.g. `:daily:` and then the problem would simplify to hiding a single tag from the weekly agenda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conveniently, `org-mode` has a function to get just the repeat out of an entry's timestamp: `org-get-repeat`.  We just have to put that in a function appropriate for `org-agenda-skip-function`, that is, it should test if `(org-get-repeat)` is equal to "+1d" for each headline.  IF it is, return the next headline, otherwise return `nil` to not skip.

```el
(defun skip-daily-tasks () 
  (let ((next-headline (save-excursion (or (outline-next-heading) (point-max))))
        (headline (or (and (org-at-heading-p) (point))
                      (save-excursion (org-back-to-heading)))))
    (if (string= (org-get-repeat) "+1d")
        next-headline
      nil)))

(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("w" "Weekly"
               agenda ""
               ((org-agenda-span 'week)
                (org-agenda-skip-function 'skip-daily-tasks))
               ))
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work with the default `d`/`w` switch yet, maybe I'll figure it out later.